# Apache2 mod_auth_form too many redirects under Location

Tags: apache, proxy, virtualhost, basic-authentication, mod-auth-form

I am trying to build a Proxy HTTP Authorisation page using `mod_auth_form`

My goal is to have a single Auth page in the `DocumentRoot` directory, then once the user is connected, just Proxy all routes to the "real" application, running on localhost with another port.

I set up my vhost with Auth directives under the root `Location` :

```
<VirtualHost *:80> 
    ServerName subdomain.example.com

    DocumentRoot /var/www/subdomain.example.com/web/

    <Location /login.html>
        Order allow,deny
        Allow from all
    </Location>

    <Location />
        SetHandler form-login-handler

        AuthType Form
        AuthName realm
        AuthFormProvider file
        AuthUserFile /var/www/subdomain.example.com/.htpasswd
        AuthFormLoginRequiredLocation "http://subdomain.example.com/login.html"

        require valid-user

        Session On
        SessionCookieName session path=/
        SessionCryptoPassphrase any-secret-passphrase      
    </Location>

    ProxyPass /login.html !
    ProxyPassReverse /login.html !
    ProxyPass / http://localhost:8888
    ProxyPassReverse / http://localhost:8888

    ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/subdomain.example.com/error.log
    CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/subdomain.example.com/access.log combined
</VirtualHost>
```

**EDIT**
Everything I needed was to reverse the order of the `<Location></Location>` directives... And add a special Location for the form handler.
Working solution:

```
<VirtualHost *:80> 
    ServerName subdomain.example.com

    DocumentRoot /var/www/subdomain.example.com/web/

    <Location />
        AuthType Form
        AuthName realm
        AuthFormProvider file
        AuthUserFile /var/www/subdomain.example.com/.htpasswd
        AuthFormLoginRequiredLocation "http://subdomain.example.com/login.html"
        AuthFormLoginSuccessLocation "http://subdomain.example.com/"

        require valid-user

        Session On
        SessionCookieName session path=/
        SessionCryptoPassphrase any-secret-passphrase      
    </Location>

    <Location /login_check.html>
        SetHandler form-login-handler

        AuthType Form
        AuthName realm
        AuthFormProvider file
        AuthUserFile /var/www/subdomain.example.com/.htpasswd
        AuthFormLoginRequiredLocation "http://subdomain.example.com/login.html"
        AuthFormLoginSuccessLocation "http://subdomain.example.com/"

        require valid-user

        Session On
        SessionCookieName session path=/
        SessionCryptoPassphrase any-secret-passphrase      
    </Location>

    <Location /login.html>
        Order allow,deny
        Allow from all
    </Location>

    ProxyPreserveHost On
    ProxyPass /login.html !
    ProxyPassReverse /login.html !
    ProxyPass / http://localhost:8888
    ProxyPassReverse / http://localhost:8888

    ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/subdomain.example.com/error.log
    CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/subdomain.example.com/access.log combined
</VirtualHost>
```

When I try to access to subdomain.example.com, I am redirected to subdomain.example.com/login.html (Which is fine!)

The content of this /var/www/subdomain.example.com/web/login.html page:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset='utf-8' />
        <meta name='viewport' content='width=device-width' />
        <title>Authentication</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <form method='POST' action='/login_check.html'>
            <div class='form-group'>
                <label for='httpd_username'>Username</label>
                <input id='http_username' class='form-control' type='text' name='httpd_username' value='' />
            </div>
            <div class='form-group'>
                <label for='httpd_password'>Password</label>
                <input id='httpd_password' class='form-control' type='password' name='httpd_password' value='' />
            </div>
            <div class='form-group'>
                <input class='btn btn-success' type='submit' name='login' value='Login' />
            </div>
        </form>
    </body>
</html>
```

However, this login.html page is never displayed, I receive a `TOO_MANY_REDIRECTS` error:

> The webpage at http://subdomain.example.com/login.html has resulted in too many redirects.

It seems that this special route has to be "down locked" by the Auth process... But I have no idea how to enable that...

I have tried to add another `ErrorDocument 401 /login.html` directive, but it did not change anything.

Comment: You could try mapping `http://localhost:8888` to a subdirectory of your subdomain (e.g. `ProxyPass /proxy/ http://localhost:8888/`) so it won't interfere with your `login.html` — at least as a temporary solution for testing. If that works, you can investigate why the `Location /login.html` doesn't seem to have an effect. (Also, your two parameters to `ProxyPass` should either both have a trailing slash or both have none.)

Comment: Thanks! Indeed, the subfolder solution works ; Except I finish with a /proxy/ in my URL, which I would prefer to avoid... Is there anyway to avoid it while keeping the subfolder?
In an other hand, how can I investigate why my ````<Location /login.html>```` is not working?
(What do you mean with the ProxyPass parameters?)

Comment: There should be a way to make your original directory layout work, but I can't say for sure how without testing the whole thing myself. I'd wager a guess that Apache is evaluating the `<Location>` blocks in the order it finds them, so the second block would override the first one. Have you tried swapping them? As for the `ProxyPass` parameters: Either have `ProxyPass /monit/ http://localhost:2812/` or `ProxyPass /monit http://localhost:2812`. I'm not entirely sure why, but I used to be unable to access some pages if only one of the parameters had a trailing slash.

Comment: You might also want to use the `retry=0` parameter to disable Apache's retry delay when the proxied site is unavailable (otherwise Apache will serve an error page for a minute after you try to access the proxied site while localhost:8888 is down): `ProxyPass / http://localhost:8888/ retry=0` (Check the parameter section of the [ProxyPass documentation](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/mod_proxy.html#proxypass) for details.)

Comment: Gosh... It was indeed just a problem of directive order... Putting /login.html at the end solves the problem... I really thought it would have been easier.
Thanks a lot!! I'll also check the ````retry=0```` parameter :)

Comment: Glad to hear it was that simple in the end. :) By the way, instead of editing the solution into your question, you could also post it as answer and mark it as accepted to provide a reference if anyone else should encounter a similar problem.

Comment: Yep, good idea. If you want to, as the solution comes from you, you can do it and I'll accept it ?
Otherwise I'll do it in a few time :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Apache parses configuration directives in the order it sees them and applies them to the specified location and everything underneath it, so the `require valid-user` from your `<Location />` block overrides the `Allow from all` from your `<Location /login.html>` block — you end up requiring authentication to access anything (including `login.html`), so you start off unauthorized when accessing `login.html` and are redirected to `login.html` to log in. There's the loop for you.

Answer (score 2):

I had the same problem using Apache 2.4, but for a different reason. With Apache 2.4+, instead of using:

```
<Location /login.html>
    Order allow,deny
    Allow from all
</Location>
```

Use:

```
<Location /login.html>
    Require all granted
</Location>
```